# Como codificar com Email Marketing?

Tags: html, css, css3, email, envio-de-email

Estou a iniciar com Email Marketing, nunca fiz antes e estou enfrentando 
 um mundo de dificuldades. Pelos tutoriais vistos na internet, pude tirar as seguintes conclusões:

- Utilizamos `table` para que tenha uma maior abrângencia e assim não tenha quebra de layout.
- Utilizamos estilo de classe com [], porque é mais convencional *ex: `tr[class="foo"]{}`
- Utilizamos estilos inline `style=""` porque as ferramentas de email não entendem a tag `<style></style>`
- A web evoluiu muito, mas a forma de fazer código para email marketing ainda está bem ultrapassado

Se tudo acima estiver certo, tenho algumas dúvidas em relação ao email marketing responsivo:

1) Tentando enviar um template responsivo de email marketing que baixei na net funciona a partir de uma ferramenta que usei chamada [PutsMail](https://putsmail.com/), mas quando tento via **GMAIL** diretamente chamado [Gmail Append HTML](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-append-html/dnfikahmfhcjfcmbgbkklecekfeijmda), ele não fica responsivo. Porque? Qual a diferença entre os dois?

2) Como funciona os `Media Queries` sendo que o estilo é inline? Até onde sei não há como colocar media queries em estilo inline

3) Em vários tutoriais de email marketing, o instrutor coloca a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` no head, se é tudo inline, como a meta tag é inserida apenas pra visualização do layout? no fim, quem vai mandar é a meta tag do site em que o usuário final acessar, certo?

Obrigado!

Comment: 2) não não tem como fazer isso inline. 3) Qualquer meta tag vai ser ignorada, não adianta... Sobre a resposividade, a tabela aceita width em %, então pode colocar as larguras dipo duas TD de 50% de largura. Vc só não vai conseguir fazer essa TD ficar com 100% em mobile e 50% em desktop, então tem que pensar o layout fluido. Dentro da TD vc pode usar floats e aligns para tentar qubrar as linhas etc. O Gmail e o Outlook em particular não aceitam quase nada de CSS, o Outlook tem até uns CSS próprios é foda de arrumar

Comment: @hugocsl Opa! Deu uma clareada!! a ferramenta MJML consegue fazer essa responsividade. apesar de eu querer fazer na mão pra aprender, ela é uma mão na roda... Como é que ela consegue resolver a questão de responsividade? Você saberia me dizer? Obrigado!!

Comment: Cara só inspecionando o código mesmo para ver o que tem lá rss. A gente aprende muito copiando o que da certo :D

Comment: Entendi... e você saberia me responder a pergunta 1? Porque via **GMAIL** não funciona a responsividade e via essa ferramenta **PostMail** funciona a responsividade?

Comment: Cara não sei dizer, só dando uma olhada no código fonte. Tenta inspecionar o código como o DevTools do Chrome e ver o que tem no corpo do email. Script e Iframes eu sei que os clientes de e-mail ignoram. Alguns ignoram tb a tag style, outros não... o Gmail até onde sei não aceita. Mas vc pode fazer uma pesquisa no Google sobre "Gmail Responsive Email"